# Tealium Tag Manager and Einstein Cart Triggers

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, einstein, einstein-recommendations

Client uses Commerce Cloud, connected to Marketing Cloud via the Cartridge, and we'd like to configure Abandoned Cart triggers using Einstein.  When we asked the client to install the Collect Code they let us know that they are using Tealium and would use the Tealium integration but I can't find any information on  how this works with Einstein.

**Question**:  Is it possible to use Tealium's tool in replacement of the Collect Code?

**Question**:  Can CC automatically send the Product Catalog to MC?

**Question**:  Shouldn't CC and SFMC automatically trigger an Abandoned Cart email since they are connected via Cartridge? Or is that too obvious and easy an answer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Search for the iGoDigital Tealium Integration.
2. The cartridge will send a Product Catalog to Marketing Cloud FTP.  This needs to be imported into the Marketing Cloud Einstein Recommendation engine.
3. This is a common feature request - stay tuned for updates.